# Plot graph but it does't show

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, graph

The scatter graph works fine, but the second graph doesn't show. There's no error message or anything. Can anyone help, please. Here's the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(xMat[:,1].flatten().A[0], yMat.T[:,0].flatten().A[0])
plt.show()

xCopy =xMat.copy()
xCopy.sort(0) #x ascending 排列
yHat = xCopy * ws #计算yHat
ax.plot(xCopy[:,1], yHat)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Use only one `plt.show()` at the end of you script

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.scatter(xMat[:,1].flatten().A[0], yMat.T[:,0].flatten().A[0])

xCopy =xMat.copy()
xCopy.sort(0) #x ascending 排列
yHat = xCopy * ws #计算yHat
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(xCopy[:,1], yHat)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. After I add    `plt.subplot(212)`    I can get a graph with only legends and axises. There's no line or anything in the graph. What I want to do is plot the first graph (use the code before xCopy), then add the second graph to the first one. The second graph should be a straight line. Could you please give me some help?

Comment: I don't have the datasets so its hard to try for me. But I obviously missunderstood the question. I think that DavidG is onto the correct solution if you want the same graph.